# SQL Count Query Query Without Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

Is there a way to simply get record counts of a query without having to populate a data extension?   I want to see how many records meet some criteria without creating a new DE, or a new filtered DE.

I know there's some 3rd party plugin (considering getting one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately to retrieve counts you will need to create a Data Extension. If your account uses Audience Builder, it is possible to quickly generate counts for dimensions already set. But then again, these dimensions have to be set by Salesforce and takes ages to them to do it.

As a quick hack you can set up a data extension with just a "Count" field, and adjust the queries for that data extension to return to counts of the population you are querying.

Comment: I agree with this 'quick hack'.  It's an unfortunate hack as I have 12 core DE's and have a group of combined data extensions, as well.

Comment: Shame. If the logic wasn't so complicated you could just run filters and it will count them but I am assuming your use case requires more granular definition